# How to write several lines of text inside curly brackets?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, brackets, braces

I would like to be able to write several lines of text inside a curly brackets in some mathematical equations. Does anyone know how to achieve multiline text such as this:

[image]

Comment: Put them into a `tabular` environment for example.

Comment: Use `\left\{ lines of text\right\}`@eurocoder

Comment: `\left\{A \:\middle\lvert\: \parbox{width}{\raggedright text $math$ text} \right\}`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Does the comments above solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using the comment of daleif you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
    A \coloneqq
    \bigcap_{\mathcal{B} \in \mathcal{S}} B =
    \left\{
    A \subset X \:\middle\lvert\:
    \parbox{45mm}{\raggedright if $\mathcal{B} \subset 2^{X}$ ist a $\sigma$-algebra such that $\mathcal{E} \subset \mathcal{B}$ then $A \in \mathcal{B}$}
    \right\}.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]